# Using AWS IOT for web socket b/w laptop and a device

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to understand if AWS IOT can help me establish a direct web socket connection from let’s say my laptop to a device both having private addresses via internet.

Let’s say I have a device with a private ip address and I want to send some data to it by via a web socket connection. 
I think AWS IOT has a way to create a direct web socket connection b/w lets say my laptop with a private ip address to the device with private address?

Something like this : 
Initially : device -> IOT connection on some topic and laptop -> IOT connection on same topic
After that a web socket b/w the device and the laptop and the traffic should be b/w laptop and the device after that

Answer (score 0):

The AWS IoT service does not provide direct device-to-device connections. The device, and your IoT laptop, would both be creating a web socket connection with the AWS IoT broker.

Using the AWS IoT broker as an intermediary should however work for your situation. You would send a message from your laptop to an AWS IoT topic that the IoT device is subscribed to, and the device would receive it immediately.

Comment: Thanks Mark.
This may be a naive question but would IOT be helpful to me if i want a real time control of my device?
If the device has a public ip address and I have a way to directly connect to it, can't I create a direct websocket connection from my browser to the device and communicate.

What benefits I would get going via IOT?

Comment: Most IoT devices are deployed in places like people's homes, or a business's network, where they are behind routers, so the devices don't have their own public IP address. If your device does have its own public IP address, then you would have to decide if the other AWS IoT features like message fan-out, trigger of AWS Lambda and other services via IoT messages, logging, etc. provide value to you.